# Allow Compiling With Errors

Tags: c#

I'm used to being able to compile source code even if it has errors due to my Java (Eclipse) background. This is a tremendous help when developing test-first, which has become my modus operandi. Also it helps a lot with refactoring.

Is there any way to achieve something similar in C#? I have to use JetBrain's Rider, but I don't care much for the IDE.

Comment: No, this is not supported by any C# compiler (although there was a Twitter thread between C# devs a few days ago discussing the possibility)

Comment: @canton7 That's a funny coincidence. Could you link the thread?

Comment: If you use Visual Studio, it can very easily generate method stubs for you that do nothing but "throw new NotImplementedException();". This will allow the code to compile. Of course any attempt to run it will throw the error. I don't know Rider but I'd be amazed if it wouldn't be able to do that as well.

Comment: No, C# doesn't work like that (nor do a lot of other languages). Although, as someone who predominantly uses C#, I'm at a loss as to how being able to compile despite a major fault that would prevent compilation would help.

Comment: @PeterB That is fine for new methods, but that is not really the most common use case. It's a lot more common to have changes to a specific type that break code in hundreds of places, but the most important place to fix and review is the type itself and it's unit tests. But I can't fix and run the unit tests without fixing the other hundreds of places, which I feel is a waste of time, especially if the change is experimental.

Comment: I see. You could unload the projects (X, Y and Z) that are failing to compile because you are refactoring the "utility" or "business" project (A), then focus on getting A to work again with your unit tests. Then you can reload X, Y and/or Z to also make those work again with A. Unloading and reloading projects is a feature of VS and most likely also of Rider.

Comment: Alternatively, you could replicate the class with the desired tweak and just incrementally alter the references you want to test.

Comment: That's what I'm doing right now. Just thought I'd ask if there is an easier way, but I guess the question is not acceptable for some reason.

Comment: To a degree, it does depend a bit on the structure of the project - in Visual Studio you can run a web app without building it for example.

Comment: I've looked through the people I follow and I can't find it I'm afraid.

Answer (score -1):

The source code could not compiled when you violate the rules of writing syntax are known as *Compile-Time errors*.

Even in Java the source code could not compiled when incorrect syntax such as a missing semicolon at the end of a statement or a missing bracket, etc.

Comment: I suspect the errors Steffi are referring to are actually Build errors - rather than syntactical faults.

Comment: You are wrong. Have you ever used Eclipse? A Java class in the Eclipse IDE will absolutely compile and even be executable until you get to the point where the syntax error resides. (At least for the cases where the class is still recognizable as a class, missing brackets is a whole other mess.)

Comment: But yes, syntax errors are not the ones I'm referring to. I just want to quickly start my tests again after refactoring, and refactorings usually do not remove brackets or semicolons.

Comment: @SteffiS. is "Will it build?" not the most fundamental test of them all?

Comment: @AndrewCorrigan Haha, true. But after a good restructuring is "Will the class be able to support the same features" a close second.

Comment: Eclipse will try and compile code with errors, e.g. by replacing the offending method body with a `throw`